# If I have multiple pages of documentation about a product can/should I place schema markup for that product on every page about that product?

Tags: schema.org

I'm guessing the answer is yes as long as the markup for the product is identical on every page?

Comment: Is this documentation about how to use the product?

Comment: Yes. But it also has a 'Buy now' button on every page of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the primary reasons for using structured data is identifying/disambiguating entities. For conveying to machines that all these pages are about the same product, you have to place the structured data on all these pages, too. Not necessarily repeating all the data, but at least providing a URI for that product.

For pages that contain documentation for the product, the primary entity should be [`TechArticle`](http://schema.org/TechArticle), not `Product`. The [`about` property](http://schema.org/about) points to the specific product the documentation is for. Example in Microdata:

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

  <article itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/TechArticle">

    <div itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
      <!-- providing the URI of the product, the add-to-cart button, etc. -->
    </div>

  </article>

</body>
```