# How to add Schema.org structured data on product pricing page?

Tags: seo, schema.org, ecommerce

We have two pages on our website:

- Product Page
  https://www.zigwheels.com/newbikes/Royal-Enfield/Classic-350
- Product Price Page
  https://www.zigwheels.com/newbikes/Royal-Enfield/Classic-350/on-road-price-bangalore

Currently, we are confused if we should include the `Product` schema in our product price page or not (although we have put it for test). My question is:

1. Should I put the same `Product` schema that I have put on the Product Page on Product Price Page too? I doubt it might create duplication kind of problem.
2. Should I put `Product` schema but with limited attributed like price, similar product etc. If yes, which all fields to include?
3. OR use different schema for price? And somehow point which product it is referring? Something [like this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/96467/if-i-have-multiple-pages-of-documentation-about-a-product-can-should-i-place-sch).

Price Schema:
https://schema.org/price

Comment: My question is, Why not? What could be the harm? I use mark-up everywhere I can. One of my sites has mark-up of some type on every page.

Comment: Any reference from Google that suggests it's okay to do so?

Comment: I have not seen one, however, I have not seen anything saying not to either. One of my sites has mark-up not only on each page, but several schemas on many pages and ranks perfectly well. Indeed, if you look around to other sites such as commercial sites, you will see mark-up on every page including several schema on many pages. Real-estate sites are famous for this mixing company info, offer, article, and others as routine.

Comment: Just because you can, it doesn't mean there is any benefit to doing so.   Google doesn't give a ranking boost for using schema. At best it gives you a rich snippet for some search results.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Understood and I agree. Just one more thing - if we add all product details in the schema of "Product Price Page" but we don't show all these details on the "Product Price Page" - would there be any penalty for that?

Also, why we have to put product details on "Product Price Page" structured data - isn't there any way to refer to google that they should pick schema from the associated "Product Page"? As otherwise we are duplicating this schema aross pages.

Comment: Why is the price on a separate page, anyway?  That seems like really poor usability for such important consumer information.   Combining the pages might be smarter than wrestling with schema.

Comment: "Should I put the same Product schema that I have put on the Product Page on Product Price Page too? I doubt it might create duplication kind of problem". I dare to suggest that Google will see duplicate content on these web pages without structured data. In my humble opinion, this is like trying to manipulate a SERP.

Answer (score 1):

For my project I personally target Buying and Price keywords on the same PDP or PLP page but in your case if you have come to the descision that they should be targeted on different URLs then I think best practice would be using Product review schema for main URL(https://www.zigwheels.com/newbikes/Royal-Enfield/Classic-350) and Price schema for Price URL(https://www.zigwheels.com/newbikes/Royal-Enfield/Classic-350/on-road-price-bangalore).